# date from date picker to sql vb10

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

*good evening i want to insert date from date picker to sql how it makes 1/1/2013 only instead of 1/1/2013 12:00AM in the table? i hope it understand thank you very much*

Comment: Ok..please post some code that [you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: sory i don't have a code that i have tried